# Searchable list of Kaggle challenges

Tags: kaggle

Is there a way to search Kaggle for a list of current and prior challenges, or an external site that does that?

When I search on Kaggle it will only bring up solution notebooks and datasets, it doesn't seem to have a filter on challenge page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the competition's stage?

In there you will see all the active and concluded contests

https://www.kaggle.com/competitions